# Google Sheets: How many cells from one column match another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column that contains multiple choice answers. I have another column for a student's answers. I want to count how many they got right by comparing the two columns. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: COUNTIF or COUNTIFS. Could say more if you provide some sample data

Comment: @user11222393 Added an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=arrayformula(SUM(N(B2:B15=C2:C15)))
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

`=arrayformula(B2:B15=C2:C15)` (example in `F2`) gives array of `TRUE/FALSE` comparing `B2` to `C2`, `B3` to `C3` and so on.
Formula `N` (example in `G2`) converts `TRUE/FALSE` array to `1/0` array. And `SUM` will return sum of `1/0` array mentioned above.

Comment: You're a wizard. Didn't know about arrayformula() and n(). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To count how many "passed", try this

```
=INDEX(SUM((B2:B9=C2:C9)+0))
```

[image]